# Attempt to import dump-file into remote MySql server generates error -"1449"

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

Attempt to import .sql file generated by mysqldump.exe into another MySQL Server generates Error - "1449: The user specified as a definer(jboss@localhost) does not exist".

So far I have attempted to -
1. Create dump using --single-transaction flag.
2. Create a user named jboss in the current MySql server.

Apparently, these methods do not seem to work.

If Could you suggest me a way in which I could configure the current MySQL server to not produce this error.
 Or,
A way, to create the dump such that it can be imported without this error.

I would be really grateful.
Thanks.

Comment: What the dump is going to import? which databse? or all databases? you created the user but with all those privileges it suppose to have? After creating user , the error is the same?

Comment: `GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'someuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'complex-password';`
`FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Comment: Hi Ijaz, It works for me, Thank you. I created the dump for all database (using --all-databases option). For creating the user I tried adding a user named jboss (something like - CREATE USER 'jboss'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'SOMEPASSWORD';). I did not grant any permission to this user explicitly, so perhaps that is the reason it was not working before.